# Fix "The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value" when author is publisher

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

How to fix "The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value" when author is also publisher?

Generaly I have an client who want hi-rate SEO website and he writte, print, sell and publish own books. Google not approve my setup and return me error in Schema.

**UPDATE**

Here is example of my problem [image]
I place `publisher` like "John Di Lemme Development Group". I do this via HTML codes, not use JSON LD for this.

Comment: Please include an example (which gives this error) in your question.

Comment: i update question

Comment: The error message is useful, too, but I meant the (minimal!) code/markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all but I find solution. Generaly I register company on Google Business Listing and after that place publisher and accept it. It's work well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Puplisher must be Person or Organision.

[Here](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=de#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usa-reisetipps.net%2Feinreise-usa%2Festa-visum) is a article sample incl author & publisher with Schema.org in HTML body without JSON LD.
I hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

The error is informing you that the itemtype you provided for the publisher property is invalid. **Whilst [schema.org](https://schema.org) does support the type *[Person](https://schema.org/Person)* for the publisher property of [Article](https://schema.org/Article), Google does not.** Google only supports *[Organization](https://schema.org/Organization)* (not [Person](https://schema.org/Person)), as the type for the publisher property, as mentioned in the Articles Structured Data page on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles).

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up  an **Author** schema, it will require either **Person** or **Organization** schemas in there. I don't know whether you're using JSON LD schemas or HTML ones. Please elaborate so I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Publisher attribute accepts a full object in JSON LD format with Organization type. Take the full object notation and pass as value. Be sure to pass the full ImageObject object notation to the logo field of Organization as well.